# It there a up limit for the size of the plot region produced by the dev.new function in R?

Tags: r

When I check the size of the plot region using

```
dev.size("in")
```

a new plot region is produced and in the Rconsole I get

```
[1] 5.333333 5.322917
```

If I mean to produce a plot region with size setting by

```
dev.new(length=3,width=3)
```

a plot region of much smaller size than that produced by using the command "dev.size("in")" appears. However, when I type the command:

```
dev.new(length=8,width=8)
```

I get a plot region of the same size with that produced by using the command "dev.size("in")", and "dev.size("in")" now indeed gives "[1] 5.333333 5.322917". It seems that the largest plot region that can be produced by "dev.new" command is 5.3x5.3 inches. Than how can I produce a larger plot region? Thank you!

Comment: This seems to be device dependent. I get `[1] 5.760417 5.750000` in the first call. Then, after resizing the graphics device, I get `[1] 7.916667 5.614583`, and it's not even the full width of my screen monitor.

Comment: The device I use a 14 inch laptop

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

[image]

My guess is that you're using RStudio, in which case, you have to redirect away from the RStudio graphics device using `dev.new(width = 3, height = 3, noRStudioGD = TRUE)`.

[image]